# Is it possible to fetch a static asset via an AJAX request?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, static, apache

Maybe my search-fu is lacking but I can't find any info on fetching static assets such as a JSON or XML file with an XHR/AJAX request. I guess it's probably web server dependant, but let's assume Apache httpd. Is this possible? If not why not?

Comment: XHR can do *any* kind of HTTP request.

Comment: As long as you can get it via an URL it is fine. An Ajax request is nothing special. In the end, it is a normal HTTP request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. XHR is just a means of sending an HTTP request to a server. The server responds to it in the usual way, no special server configuration is required.

*Browsers* impose some restrictions on XHR. Specifically, by default they only allow you to use XHR to request a resource that has the same *origin* as the document in which the script running the XHR is loaded; this is called the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). So if my script is loaded by a document on `http://example.com`, I can't use XHR to request `http://foo.com/index.html`.

There's a new(ish) standard called [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/) that lets browsers and servers work together to make exceptions to that policy. CORS is supported in modern browsers, although sadly in IE it's only supported via the `XDomainRequest` object (and only in IE8 and up), not the usual `XMLHttpRequest` object. (Firefox and Chrome support it in `XMLHttpRequest`, and hopefully someday Microsoft will see the light as well.)

Comment: Sure. But the HTTP headers specify it's an XHR request, just wondered if this would mean they were dealt with in a special way. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Richard: Not unless your server is configured to treat them specially. I've never seen a *default* configuration that did. Doesn't mean there aren't any, of course. :-)

Comment: Ok great. I've only ever used ajax with dynamic web apps, but have a situation that would be greatly simplified with static assets.

Answer (score 0):

Static resources are nothing different in HTTP world. When you make an AJAX call, you use a URL with a specified **Extension** (like png or pdf). Web server sees that extension, and serves that, no matter what who how made the request (of course, if you don't interfere with that). Let's assume that you use jQuery ajax. The response would be available to you as the parameter of the success callback:

```
$.ajax({
    // parameters here
    success: function (response) {
        // Here you have access to response.
    }
});
```